# Adding checkmark to selected table cell also checks another table cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

When adding a checkmark to selected table cells, im seeing check appear in other cells also.

my didSelectRowAtIndexPathCode is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PFObject *player = [squadListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *playerName = [player valueForKey:@"fullName"];
    NSLog(@"%@", playerName);

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

The NSLog has expect results, only showing the one selection.

Any ideas? Do you need me to show any other code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can't be configuring the cell properly when the cell gets reused. You should always be setting (and resetting) all of the properties of the cell from your data model.

---

You must have a data model that is being used to tell the table view how many rows it has and what each cell should look like. During `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you should be updating your data model with the `selected` information. Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you can use the information in the data model to decide if the cell has a checkmark or not. If it does you add it, if it doesn't you explicitly remove it (to prevent it being left there if the cell was reused).

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 1):

Your cell is being recycled by other rows. In the method, `cellforrowatindexpath`, add the following line at the end:

```
selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cells are cached and re-used.  You need to only save the fact you were selected (maybe in PFObject) and then set the accessory each time you configure a cell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly tell that you don't want other cells to have the checkmark.

```
if ([self shouldSelectCell]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing the following:

1. Create NSMutableSet that holds the indexes of selected cells.

   ```
   @property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableSet *selectedCells;


   -(NSMutableSet *)selectedCells{
       if(_selectedCells){
           return _selectedCells;
       }
       _selectedCells = [[NSMutableSet alloc]init];
       return _selectedCells;
   }
   ```
2. On didSelect update the set and select the cell:

   ```
       -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
           UITableViewCell *cell =  [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
           cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
           [self.selectedCells addObject:indexPath];
           [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
       }
   ```
3. Remove the indexPath on didDEselect

   ```
   -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
       UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
       [self.selectedCells removeObject:indexPath];
   }
   ```
4. Inside the

   ```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   ```

   update the cell as:

   ```
   if([self.selectedCells containsObject:indexPath]){
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
   }else{
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
   }
   ```